# URL schema and open program

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, url-scheme

my iPhone program use a URL schema and work successful, to do this is only [fallow this tutorial](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html). Ok, when the program start, i use the function

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions;
```

And the **launchOptions** have all data that I need. This problem is solved. BUT, and when I use the URL schema and my program IS OPEN. Ok, the program open and show the last windows that was in it. But I want to go to another place.

The question: How can I know the program was reactivated from a web browser with a URL Schema? What function I have to use? I didn't found any that can solve it.

Comment: Are you looking for: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
 in UIApplicationDelegate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES... The correct function is this!!!! (Thanks onnoweb)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

It's a little obscure, why not use "wasOpenedByURL". Bah.. I have to use all function in a object to know what it do.